# Form textbox not editable

Tags: html, angular, forms, textbox

The textbox in my form needs to display data stored in the database but it also needs to be editble. At the moment it's displaying data but you can't click on it.

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="groupedVolumes">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let model of groupKeys() | slice:-3" >
        <tr>
            <th class="model">{{ carValues(model)[0].model }}</th>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let value of carValues(model)">
                <td input type='text' class="data" name="sceheduledData">
                    {{ value.scheduledVolume }}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>                
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "you can't click on it"? You can click on any pixel you move your mouse cursor over....

Comment: I can't click on to the field to edit the data

Comment: Why can't you do that? What **exactly** does that mean?